# How to perform multiple axios POST requests in a For Loop with different body data for each iteration of loop?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I have an array of postData whose each element is the body that needs to be passed in every time we make an Axios POST request.

I am facing unhandled promise rejection error when running the script, i am fairly new to asynchronous programming and have been struggling with this error.

The script goes like this:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

var textFileContainingData = fs.readFileSync('data.txt').toString().split("\r\n");
console.log(textFileContainingData);

let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXX',
        'X-Correlation-ID': '1234',
    }
  };

for (i=0; i<textFileContainingData.length; i++) {
    
    var postData = {
        data: textFileContainingData[i]
    };

    console.log(postData)
    
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            return await axios.post('https://example-api-url/endpoint', postData, axiosConfig)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
          
    const callEndpoint = async () => {
        const responseData = await getData()
    
        console.log(responseData)
    }
    
    callEndpoint();
}
```

Comment: May you show the rejection error ?

Comment: await callEndpoint();
    ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
?[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)?[39m

Comment: No sorry this was my fault, remove the await before callEndpoint() and show me the error from your code in the question

Comment: Okay, i think the problem was with the For Loop, i changed it to the format you suggested and now it is working fine. Thanks! There is one other doubt though that I added a console.log statement after the for loop to execute and show that for loop execution is complete but that is getting executed even before the entire completion of the loop! Any help?

Comment: So, the axios requests are working perfectly and added a setTimeOut to print the console.log after the for loop by providing enough time to complete the requests.

Comment: this is the whole idea of async, you leave something working in the background and do anything, anything added after callEndpoint (without await) will execute while it's executing (mostly before), kindly upvote my answer as the old one is downvoted, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have upvoted it, but seems like my vote reflect until my reputation is below 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was mistaken, I've removed it.
The error is related to a promise, probably axios.post is failing, post your stacktrace after trying your code

Some additional notes:

1. Use .forEach for readability
2. use `axios.post({}).then(response => {}).catch(err => {})`, you may omit .then and leave only `.catch()`